# The camera traspass a part of wall in first person Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

When I was testing my game written in Unity 3D, I see that the camera traspass the wall on the left superior part but in the right superior part don't do it.

Can anybody help me please?

A picture - the error is up at the left:

[image: The error is Up at the left]

Comment: That's a simple near plane culling issue.  Adjusting it should fix it.  However, if you are trying to represent something that is _massive_ or _far away_ you can use Unity Stacked Cameras, each with their own near, far clip settings and world scale.  Great for flight simulators or massive open world games.

Answer (score 0):

The wall is closer than the shortest distance at which the camera can render. The distance is called near clipping plane. You can change it from the inspector after you select the camera. Set it to a very small number like 0.01 to render objects at a very close distance and avoid this issue.
[image]
Keep in mind that as your far/near ratio increases, your depth buffer precision will decrease which can cause some artifacts. So only reduce the near plane/increase the far plan as much as you really need.